# Match Operator prettier syntax in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm very new to groovy (here working on Jenkinsfile)

One of my coworkers uses a [Match Operator](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-pattern-matching#match-operator) to check a condition. But I find it not readable and hard to maintain.

Original Match Operator:

```
PROJECT_NAME = 'projectA' // User Input from Jenkins params normaly
if ( "${PROJECT_NAME}" ==~ /projectA|projectB|projectC|projectD/) { // The real line is 300 Char long
    // Do stuff
}
```

There is 15 projects in total, i've shorten up the line because it was too long. So every time he needs to add a project name, he appends at the start or end of his regex.

Also, those project name are in a list before.

```
projects = ['projectA',
    'projectB',
    'projectC',
    'projectD']
```

Could there be a way to use this list to build the regex?

Here is what I tried:

```
string_regex = "/"
for (project in projects) {
    string_regex = string_regex + project + "|" 
}
string_regex = string_regex.substring(0, string_regex.length() - 1)
string_regex = string_regex + "/"

print "${string_regex}\n"

if ("${PROJECT_NAME}" ==~ string_regex) {
    print "Well Done you did it\n"
    // Do stuff
}
```

But saddly it doesn't seems to work, since I'm using a string?

EDIT: I found out that I could use the `contains` method from a list in Groovy. In my case, it fixes my original problem. But I'm still curious on how to build such regex with strings.

```
if (projects.contains(PROJECT_NAME)) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: `contains` is definitely the better way to do this. I would not worry about trying to do it the other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` your projects and then turn the string into a regexp via `Pattern.compile()`.  For good measure use `Pattern.quote()` to safe-guard against chars in your project names with "meaning" in regexp.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

def projects = ['projectA',
    'projectB',
    'projectC',
    'projectD']

def re = Pattern.compile(projects.collect{ Pattern.quote it }.join("|"))

['projectA', 'projectX'].each{
    println it ==~ re
}
// -> true
// -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I came to like the Groovy matching operators for their compact syntax. If you learn about them and practice for a short bit, you will probably get to like them, too.

Regardless, for a simple check, on whether a String is part of a list, there is a much simpler way in Groovy than using full blown regexp : the `in` operator, e.g.:

```
def projects = ['projectA',
    'projectB',
    'projectC',
    'projectD']

['projectA', 'projectX'].each {
    println "${it} is ${it in projects ? 'IN' : 'NOT IN'} the project list"
}
```

which yields e.g.:

```
projectA is IN the project list
projectX is NOT IN the project list
```

More info on that operator and many other aspects of the Groovy language from the always excellent MrHaki [here](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-are-you-in-membership.html)

Of course, if you need to account for case differences, etc... you have to massage the code a bit, but at some point, a regexp might be warranted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already an **collection**, you should nearly always use an **collection operator**; E.g. replace

```
if ( "${PROJECT_NAME}" ==~ /projectA|projectB|projectC|projectD/) {
```

with:

```
if (PROJECT_NAME in projects) {
```

Much easier to read and understand, no?